# Rails 3 Assets not available in deployed development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, assets, capistrano3

We have a rails 3 application being deployed using capistrano 3 in development mode. Capistrano compiles the assets and the site displays properly. However some of the site functionality is not working and using "inspect" in chrome it shows that none of the css of js files are not present.

The site can be viewed at [here](https://eng1.lifefoodsinc.com).

How can I set capistrano that it does not compile assets when deploying to this server?

I am not sure what other information I should be providing, so please let me know and I will update the question accordingly.

## EDIT

1) Corrected the site URL.

2) [development.rb](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8ccea2ef3e46c51e5c77) file

3) Using capistrano3 with [Capfile](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/31c58df0dacf5d76e218)

Comment: The page in question is a default Nginx page… Could you clarify whether you have the asset pipeline enabled on the server, or whether you are using asset precompilation (which is usually a better idea on a server)? Also, your Capfile would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry the url was incorrect, I have updated it. I have also added the development.rb file showing what I have on server as well as the Capfile.

Comment: It seems that your asset has not been compile on using inspect element in chrome , try with `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile`

Comment: but I do not want to compile the assets. As this is a development environment I want them to be served directly.